# ffmpeg relocation error, debian

Tags: ffmpeg, libavcodec, libavformat

Getting following error after run ffmpeg:

```
$ ffmpeg                   
ffmpeg: relocation error: ffmpeg: symbol av_stream_get_codec_timebase, version LIBAVFORMAT_57 not defined in file libavformat.so.57 with link time reference
```

Same for avconv.

Comment: Did you compile ffmpeg yourself ?
It seems ffmpeg binary and it's libraries has some version conflict.

Comment: I used apt, only debian stretch repositories.

Comment: Either uninstall/remove ffmpeg, update debian repositories (if available) and reinstall ffmpeg. If still situation is same, compile ffmpeg yourself, it's not that hard (maybe a little) follow documents on official web site.